# Do I need to check if an value is null before calling Objects.hash()?

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

I have a custom objects which properties include integers (e.g. `Integer num1` and `Integer num2`) that can be `null`.

For the equal function, I determine if 2 of my custom objects are equal by doing `return num1 == customObj.num1 && num2 == customObj.num2`. This works b/c `null == null` is `true` in Java.

So I was wondering if in my object's hashcode function it would be okay to do `return Objects.hash(num1, num2)`?

I'm just not sure if I can pass `null` objects to `Objects.hash(...)` and if that would mess up the hashcode in some way or if I'd get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Before asking a question about a method please consider reading its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-) first. Else people will find that you did not show *any research effort* which is a reason for down-voting. You may also run a small test and just call the method with some `null` values and see what happens, it will work as the documentation states.

Comment: Yes and my instructor will also give me a two week extension for this project. Sometimes time urgency supersedes the annoyance of being down-voted by stack overflow elitist (and by the looks of the star seems like other people have this question too!)

Comment: Note that unless you're actually trying to check for having the same `Integer` instances, you should be using `Objects.equals(num1, customObj.num1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Objects#hashcode`

As mentioned in docs [Objects#hashcode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) only generate `hash code` for a non-null argument and 0 if the argument is `null`. Eventually you will never get `NullPointerException`.

> Returns the hash code of a non-null argument and 0 for a null
>   argument.

---

If you have multiple fields you can use its overloaded version `Objects#hash(Object... values)`
As per docs

> Generates a hash code for a sequence of input values. The hash code is
>   generated as if all the input values were placed into an array, and
>   that array were hashed by calling Arrays.hashCode(Object[]).

Comment: but i have multiple attributes, not just one. How would I combine the hashcodes generated from `num1` and `num2`?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @14wml Just look it up in the documentation. `Objects#hash` (which you want to call) is like calling `Arrays.hashCode(Object[]).` on the provided arguments. Looking up that method yields `Arrays.asList(a).hashCode()` or *"unless a is null, in which case 0 is returned."* So your method works for `null`.

Answer (score 11):

You have to do a little bit of digging through the documentation to find what the behaviour will be if one of these references is null.

[`Objects.hash(Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-) says:

> The hash code is generated as if all the input values were placed into an array, and that array were hashed by calling `Arrays.hashCode(Object[])`.

[`Arrays.hashCode(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode-java.lang.Object:A-) says:

> The value returned by this method is equal to the value that would be returned by `Arrays.asList(a).hashCode()`

`Arrays.asList(Object[])` returns a `List`, and [`List.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--) says:

> The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:
>
> ```
> int hashCode = 1;
> for (E e : list)
>   hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
> ```

So null elements will be handled the same as objects with hash code zero.

Whilst it took a bit of digging to reach this answer, a much simpler strategy would have been to have just tried it - you could have got your answer more quickly like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of testing equality is broken.

While it works when both `Integer` objects are `null`, it generally won't work when they are non-null. You are comparing the objects' references instead of their numeric values.

Use [`Objects.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) to perform a null-safe test using the objects' `equals()` method. While you're there, read the manual for [`Objects.hashCode()`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-)